# cscope error while loading shared libraries

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, cscope

While running cscope tool on linux OS, I got below error.

#### cscope: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I searched for libncurses.so.4 lib in /usr/lib, it doesnot exist but libncurses.so.5 lib do exist. So how to resolved this problem, Do I need to specifically give so.5 path to cscope?

Comment: Are you using a 64 bit machine ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have ncurses, try installing with the below command.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5
```

Also, If its a 64 bit machine you might have to install some additional packages.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but this machine does not have outbound access.

Answer (score 0):

I simply created link of libncurses.so.4 for so.5 and it worked.

```
ln -s libncurses.so.5 libncurses.so.4
```

Now cscope command is working fine, thanks for your replies.